# Improving Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, database, performance, linq-to-entities

I have the following query:

```
if (idUO > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(b => b.Product.Center.UO.Id == idUO);
}
else if (dependencyId > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(b => b.DependencyId == dependencyId );
}
else
{
    var dependencyIds = dependencies.Select(d => d.Id).ToList();

    query = query.Where(b => dependencyIds.Contains(b.DependencyId.Value));
}

[...] <- Other filters...

if (specialDateId != 0)
{
    query = query.Where(b => b.SpecialDateId == specialDateId);
}
```

So, I have other filters in this query, but at the end, I process the query in the database with:

```
return query.OrderBy(b => b.Date).Skip(20 * page).Take(20).ToList(); // the returned object is a Ticket object, that has 23 properties, 5 of them are relationships (FKs) and i fill 3 of these relationships with lazy loading
```

When I access the first `page`, its OK, the query takes less than one 1 second, but when I try to access the page 30000, the query takes more than 20 seconds. There is a way in the linq query, that I can improve the performance of the query? Or only in the database level? And in the database level, for this kind of query, which is the best way to improve the performance?

Comment: what is the type of query object?

Comment: Woah. I forgot, i will put in the question.

Comment: I would recommend filtering your query a little bit further. A query that returns 600,000 records isn't really usable in a human context (which is suggested by the need for paging). Unless you're working on a search engine of some kind, and then in that case Linq is probably not the tool you'd want.

Comment: @JoelEtherton the query will not returns 600k of records, because i filter with a TOP 20, look to the `.Take(20)` in the end of the query.

Comment: Have you tried profiling this code? It might turn out that the bottleneck is the DB itself.

Comment: No, i didn't profile this code. Which is the best way to do that? How the DB can be the bottleneck?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: If you have 30,000 pages each with 20 records, then the base query returns 600k. That's far too many. Your initial query should be refined to return fewer records to start with.

Comment: I suppose you are using MS SQL Server. If you are not on Express edition, there is an [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091) out-of-the-box.. For Express edition [this one](https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/) should do. Profilers allow to examine each request to the database, see the SQL code and the running time. If from those 20 seconds query execution in DB took 19 - that is a sign that you might need to think about DB structure optimization.

Comment: @Andrei I will try the SQL Profiler, and back to say the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find that the bottleneck is occurring at the database. Here's why;

query.

You have your query, and the criteria. It goes to the database with a pretty ugly, but not too terrible select statement.

.OrderBy(b => b.Date)

Now you're ordering this giant recordset by date, which probably isn't a terrible hit because it's (hopefully) indexed on that field, but that does mean the entire set is going to be brought into memory and sorted before any skipping or taking occurs.

.Skip(20 * page).Take(20)

Ok, here's where it gets rough for the poor database. Entity is pretty awful at this sort of thing for large recordsets. I dare you to open sql profiler and view the random mess of sql it's sending over.

When you start skipping and taking, Entity usually sends queries that coerce the database into scanning the entire giant recordset until it finds what you are looking for. If that's the first ordered records in the recordset, say page 1, it might not take terribly long. By the time you're picking out page 30,000 it could be scanning a lot of data due to the way Entity has prepared your statement.

I highly recommend you take a look at the following link. I know it says 2005, but it's applicable to 2008 as well.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/article.php/c19611/Paging-in-SQL-Server-2005.htm

Once you've read that link, you might want to consider how you can create a stored procedure to accomplish what you're going for. It will be more lightweight, have cached execution plans, and is pretty well guaranteed to return the data much faster for you.

Barring that, if you want to stick with LINQ, read up on [Compiled Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx) and make sure you're setting MergeOption.NoTracking for read-only operations. You should also try returning an Object Query with explicit Joins instead of an IQueryable with deferred loading, especially if you're iterating through the results and joining to other tables. Deferred Loading can be a real performance killer.

Comment: L2E also uses the `OVER` clause, what's the difference with the sample SP?

Comment: @Stijn What you'll often find in entity is that it does odd things with unions and top @@topNumber where row_count() > @@somenumber rather than straight forward joins and row_count() >= @@firstnumber and row_count() <= @@secondNumber. Top, with order, with union, with > is going to be more expensive than methods outlined in the link. That being said, viewing the generated L2E sql is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no much space here, imo, to make things better (at least looking on the code provided).

When you're trying to achieve a good performance on such numbers, I would recommend do not use  `LINQ` at all, or at list use it on the stuff with smaler data access.

What you can do here, is introduce paging of that data on `DataBase` level, with some `stored procedure`, and invoke it from your `C#` code.

Comment: What you mean with "introduce paging of that data on Database level"? The `.Skip(20 * page).Take(20)` is not enough to do that? Why?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: I mean writing StoreProcedure on *server* (writtent in SQL) that runs paging on *server* and returns to you only raws you need.

Comment: So, `.Skip(20 * page).Take(20)` don't create this paging? Taking only the raws that i need with TOP 20 = `.Take(20)`?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni Yes, it does create paging. I think Tigran doesn't fully understand the code.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni: yes, but it runs sql query (should be checked if it's converted in good SQL), in case of stored procedure, the performance could be a  way different.

Answer (score 1):

1- Create a view in DB which orders items by date including all related relationships, like Products etc.

2- Create a stored procedure querying this view with related parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you pull up SQL Server Profiler, and run a profile on the server while you run the queries (both the fast and the slow).
Once you've done this, you can pull it into the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to get some tips about Indexes that you should add.. This has had great effect for me in the past. Of course, if you know what indexes you need, you can just add them without running the Advisor :)